# Can this be solved?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that 47% of all Americans have flown in an airplane at least once and that 28% of all Americans have ridden on a train at least once. What is the probability that a randomly selected American has either ridden on a train or flown in an airplane? Can this problem be solved? Under what conditions can it be solved? If the problem cannot be solved, what information is needed to make it solvable?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have information enough to answer that. The numbers you have are consistent with two different extreme situations:

```
A: 28% have traveled both by train and plane
   19% have traveled by plane only
   0% have traveled by train only
   53% have not traveled at all
```

or

```
B: 0% have traveled both by train and plane
   47% have traveled by plane only
   28% have traveled by train only
   25% have not traveled at all.
```

So the best you can say is that the answer is between 47% and 75%.

What would we need to get an answer? If you know how many have traveled by *both* modes, you can reason like rlartiga's answer does.

If you knew that "has traveled by train" and "has traveled by plane" are **statistically independent**, the fraction who have traveled both ways is $0.47\cdot0.28$. But independence is a very strong assumption, and it doesn't seem to be a reasonable one in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B) $$ 
A: Event in which the person  have flown in an airplane at least once

B: Event in which the person have ridden on a train at least once

You are asking for A or B probability, then for $A \cup B$ but according with the formula you need the info about the probability of being traveled in both media.